# About $ character in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a code section below :

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MainConnStr %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT [au_id], [au_lname], [au_fname], [state] FROM [authors]" />
```

What is meaning of The $ character in value of ConnectionString attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's referred to as an ASP.NET Expression. You can pull config information such as ConnectionStrings or AppSettings as well as Resources.

[ASP.NET Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[They're expressions, read about them here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)

[Read about *all inline tags* here](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)